# Creating list np.arange

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create list, so I used:

```
x_ticks=np.arange(x1, x2, 6)
print(x_ticks)
print(type(x_ticks))
print(x_ticks[5])
```

The result is:

```
[-1.15e-14]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "el_motion.py", line 371, in <module>
    print(x_ticks[5])
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Why there are not 6 elements printed? Thank you

**EDIT**

How to plot small lines in 3d using this list and for cycle?

```
x1=-1.15e-14
x2=0.009e-14
x_ticks=np.linspace(x1, x2, 6)
print(x_ticks)
print(type(x_ticks))
print(x_ticks[5])

stepx=(x2-x1)/6
print(stepx)
for xi in range(1, 6):
    ax.plot([xi*stepx, xi*stepx], [-6.3e-15, -6.4e-15], [0,0])
```

the result is one line that is not on the desired place. I would like to print it in the plane z, the length of the lines is set by y and the starting points are defined by x.

Comment: What are x1 and x2?

Comment: The third value is step size, not number of values.  Were you thinking of `linspace`?

Comment: `stepx=(x2-x1)/5` is the correct difference.  The number of elements, and the number of spaces is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the difference between x1 and x2 is less that the provided step interval (6). For example:

```
np.arange(1, 5)
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

whereas for

```
np.arange(1, 5, 6)
```

6 is too large of a step, therefore it returns only the first value

```
[1]
```

np.linspace(x1, x2, 6) on the other hand, will return x1 one and x2 evenly spaced increments between, resulting in 6 numbers

Comment: Thank you I tried a code that I added to my question. Why the values are not between those two values?

Comment: It appears that they are.
[-1.150e-14 -9.182e-15 -6.864e-15 -4.546e-15 -2.228e-15  9.000e-17]
can also be written as
[-1.150e-14 -0.9182e-14 -0.6864e-14 -0.4546e-14 -0.2228e-14  0.009e-14]

Answer (score 4):

The 3rd arguments of numpy [arange()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) is `step`, the number of elements depends on `x1`, `x2`, and `6`, you might want to print out `x_ticks`. Examples:

```
>>> np.arange(0, 24, 6)
array([ 0,  6, 12, 18])
>>> np.arange(0, 30, 6)
array([ 0,  6, 12, 18, 24])
```